# How to query pre-existing table from SQlAlchemy ORM session?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy to do some data processing and create some tables. I'm loading data from an table `orm_table` defined with the `Declarative Base` class `ORMTable`, so can query the database with the `session.query(ORMTable).all()` statement.

However, I also need to query another table `non_orm_table` that already exists in the database and is not defined in the orm. How do I query this table from within the same session? I don't have a class associated with it so wondering what is the standard practice for such cases?

Comment: Could you define a model for the preexisting table?

Comment: if that is needed I could. But the table is already there, so I was hoping there's a way to just pull that information for particular tables I'm interested in into what the ORM can work with.

Comment: Take a look at sqlalchemy.ext.automap. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the code snippet to make it:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine('<db_connection_string>', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base(engine)


class NonOrmTable(Base):
    """
    eg. fields: id, title
    """
    __tablename__ = 'non_orm_table'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload': True}


def loadSession():
    """"""
    metadata = Base.metadata
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()
    return session


if __name__ == "__main__":
    session = loadSession()
    res = session.query(NonOrmTable).all()
    print res[1].title
```

The key is to use `SqlAlchemy’s autoload` attribute. It will map the existing table field names to the class dynamically.

I hope it helps.

Comment: had to also use `autoload_with` in the __table_args__ but yah this certainly did help. exactly what I was looking for. thanks ! i've accepted your answer.

Comment: yeah, you still have to bind the class with the existing table.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it as below.

```
  #Considering account is your table and first_name is a column

  from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select, MetaData, Table

  CONN = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://username:password@localhost:5432/dbname', 
  client_encoding="UTF-8") 
  META_DATA = MetaData(bind=CONN, reflect=True)
  account = META_DATA.tables['account']
  stmt = select([account]).where(account.columns.first_name == 'Michael')
  connection = CONN.connect()
  results = connection.execute(stmt).fetchall()

  # to print the result
  for result in results:
      print(result)
```

Comment: I'd second the reflect method here (as has been pointed out in other answers to questions like this); extremely convenient!!!